# Google Sheet - Conditional Formatting for MAX value per row

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet for a game that I play (EvE Online), and this is the table I use:

[image]

I'd like to know how can I make conditional formatting to highlight the MAX value comparing columns I (corp total) and column M (market total) for each line, my goal is to have these values highlighted as an example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE($I1:M),"select 
 "&REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(,ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(I1:I),"max(Col"&ROW(I1:I)- 
 ROW(I1)+1&"),",""))),".\z",""))),"select Col2")
```

[image: 0]